# Switch to button controlled game instead of keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard

I'm building a simple browser game with html5 and java. Initially I managed controls of the game with the keyboard, now I'm trying to switch controls from keyboard to buttons, but nothing seems to work. I have no idea how to make the correct way. Here's my code with keyboard controls:

```
//Keyboard controls
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        var key = e.keyCode;

        if (key == 37) {
            dir = "left";
            player.isMovingLeft = true;
        } else if (key == 39) {
            dir = "right";
            player.isMovingRight = true;
        }

        if(key == 32) {
            if(firstRun === true) {
                init();
                firstRun = false;
            }
            else 
                reset();
        }
    };
```

And my not working button code:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
            var onclick = e.clickEvent;

            if (onclick = "btn1") {
                dir = "left";
                player.isMovingLeft = true;
            } else if (onclick = "btn2") {
                dir = "right";
                player.isMovingRight = true;
            }
        };
```

Thanks in advance, every help is appreciated!

Comment: `question=java || question=javascript ? ++ : --;`

Comment: How is your "not working button code" not working? :)

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
        var onclick = e.target.id; // e.target gets the element which originally triggered the event

        if (onclick == "btn1") { // watch out for == instead of =
            dir = "left";
            player.isMovingLeft = true;
        } else if (onclick == "btn2") {
            dir = "right";
            player.isMovingRight = true;
        }
};
```